# Does installation cause changes to Windows partition?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

When I install Ubuntu, does it cause change or something else in the Windows partition?

Comment: "exchanges" or "changes"? they seem to mean a different thing. Please make it clear. "Exchanges" seems to mean "transactions", of which NO, Ubuntu won't mess with Windows File System and its files/folders. BUT! If you are trying to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows, then YES. Ubuntu will modify the partition table where Windows resides in order to make enough room for its installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a system with Windows already installed, Ubuntu's installer will  usually *shrink down* Windows's partition(s) to make room to create its own. This **does** modify the partition--it physically moves the files in it so that they are not as far apart--but it *shouldn't* change the contents of any of your files or where they exist in the Windows filesystem (i.e., a particular file may be relocated physically on disk but you should still find it in the same place in Windows that you found it before).

If you're wondering if you ought to make sure your backups of important files on Windows are current before installing Ubuntu, the answer is yes. There's a small chance that dynamically shrinking the Windows partition will cause data loss, and usually a somewhat larger chance of the user making a mistake that could cause data loss. For example, if you accidentally tell Ubuntu to install using *the entire disk*, then it will overwrite the contents of other OSes, which would result in you losing the files in your Windows system.

Furthermore, you should always maintain current backups of your important files (such as documents); if you don't have such a backup, now's a great time to create one, before installing Ubuntu. If your Windows system is broken and will not boot (sometimes that's what interests people in using Ubuntu), you can use the Ubuntu live CD/DVD, the same one you'd use to install, to access those files. So even if your Windows system is broken, you can back up any important documents in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Ubuntu on a different partition than your windows partition. Ubuntu will not access the windows partition.

Comment: The question is asking about what happens *when Ubuntu is installed*. During installation, Ubuntu typically *will* change the Windows partition, to shrink it and make room for Ubuntu's partitions.